# Analogs of line height in JavaFX CSS

Tags: java, css, button, javafx

After increasing font size for button to 18 px, label on button slightly moved down and now part of text is not visible. I've tried to use -fx-content-display: top; and -fx-translate-y: -5px; but it didn't help. Same goes for combobox. Is there a better way to position text/change line height than separatly creating button and label? Also is there any way to add a letter-spacing?
Button code:

```
.button{
-fx-background-image: url("images/reg_button.png");
-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
-fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semilight";
-fx-font-size:18;
-fx-alignment:center;
-fx-text-fill: white;
-fx-background-insets: 0, 0, 1, 2;
-fx-translate-y: -5px;
-fx-content-display: top;}
```

[image]

Comment: How is the layout of the button managed? (I.e. what layout pane is it in, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are using Scene Builder and setting the button prefered size to 201x31, and min/max sizes to `USER_PREF_SIZE`.

The default insets (including padding) for a button using modena.css are these:

```
-fx-padding: 6 12 6 12;
```

If the button's height is fixed to 31 px, this means you have 19 px free for the text height. The label is rendered 6 pixels from top, so that's why it gets cut on the bottom.

So you need to modify this to your convenience to gain more space, for instance:

```
.button{
    -fx-background-image: url("image/reg_button.png");
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Semilight";
    -fx-font-size:18;
    -fx-alignment:center;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-content-display: top;
    -fx-padding: 0 0 3 0;
}
```

And get something like this:

[image: button]

Comment: I used JavaFX Scene Builder and specified padding there 0. I tried to add -fx-padding: 3; to the CSS code. I even tried to change padding to 0, but it still has no effect. Pref. button size is 201x31. Min width/height, max width/height are set to use_pref_size.

Comment: Really strange thing that after I added .button .text{-fx-padding:0;} it started to show properly. And it continues even after I removed it. But it is not stable. Label can show properly or can slide down like in the picture that I provided above. Seems like a bug. Even though can't solve it with combobox(padding 0). Are there any ways to change letter spacing to 75?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Setting padding values can be done in css or in SB. You can use only the bottom value, to decrease the baseline offset

Comment: I've found that SB may not be very reliable in this case, updating padding via CSS file was refreshed on SB, but closing and opening again the FXML file led to different results. Anyway, run your application and see for yourself if the text is well aligned.

Comment: Letter spacing is not supported. There's a feature request for this [here](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-36099).